# android: how to send notification from the server to the app

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to send a notification vi web server to the app, actually I know how to use notification manager but i could not implement an activity or service that would listen if there any notification come from the web server . How could I do that ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a platform agnostic solution, you could also look at Parse Push. The API is very easy to implement in your app. https://parse.com/products/push

Comment: thank you very much, it is very helpful but currently i don't prefer to pay money.